# consume a web service in nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Normally in angular.js I was used to consuming a web service GET, in which I passed 2 parameters, as follows.

```
 $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+tweet.lat+','+tweet.long+'&key=AIzaSyBZVOSPh0Z4mv9jljJWzZNSug6upuec7Sg')
 .then(function(result){

  }, function(error){

  }
```

How can I get this same result directly in nodejs?. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several way to do this. A lot of people use the `request` module, which makes things about the same as angular:

You'll need to install request (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) with:

```
npm install request
```

and then:

```
var request = require('request');
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    // do stuff with response & body.
});
```

If you want promises, there is also a request-promise module available on npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise).

```
npm install --save request
npm install --save request-promise
```

You need both `request` and `request-promise` in this case.

```
var request = require('request-promise');

request(url)
.then(function (result) {
    // do stuff with result
})
.catch(function (err) {
    //error
});
```

Also you can use the `http` module built into node, but then you'll need to manage the stream yourself.

Comment: When you speak of promises, you mean .then().? if, your answer is yes, I wanted to do it with promises.

Comment: Yes, @yavg, .then() is a promise function. I updated the answer, but it's basically copy and paste from request-promise docs.

Comment: htmlString is the answer of the petition web?

Comment: htmlString will be the result from the web service. Not necessarily html, of course.